# Letter's found at new construction sites

Tags: construction

I realized that for along while when arriving at new construction sites, mostly residential, I see the same 3 capitalized letters spray painted on the road directly in front of the work zone. What do the letters "U S A" pertain to in regards to the construction industry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marks the location for having utility lines possibly crossing the construction area found and marked with painted lines.  This is required anytime excavation takes place in an area the utilities might be.  One of the common companies that does this, or at least a phone hotline to these people is called [USA digs.](http://usanorth811.org/)

Comment: Here, the local equivalent is DIG-SAFE.

Comment: user2448131- so USA is the companies "tag". Underground Service Alert, got it.

Comment: Dig-rite and Dig-safe are both companies that operate one call hotlines in various states. The phone numbers are convenient to remember 1-800-dig-rite and 1-800-dig-safe.  I happen to know that Missouri uses dig-rite and Kansas uses dig-safe. I'm not certain about other states, I googled for a list by state for this comment but didn't find such quickly. @ojait